# Python3: Base Constructor getting called implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, derived-class

So I really don't understand how Python3 handles constructors. Most questions here seem to have the problem that their base constructor is *not* called, I've got the problem (I think) that it is being called.
What I'm trying to do is to define a class whose constructor returns a bytes objects based on some other data passed in the constructor.

```
class MyObj(bytes):
    def __init__(self, data):
        ## do stuff to calculate a bytes_object from data
        ## in the C++ example below, I just reinterpret_cast the data
        ## call super(MyObj, self).__init__(bytes_object) to invoke
        ## the copy constructor
        pass

construct_MyObj_for_this_data = [0.4,2.5,12.1]
newmyobj = MyObj(construct_MyObj_obj_for_this_data)
```

If this is run in the Interpreter, I get this:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It seems that `MyObj()` is always calling the Base (i.e. bytes) constructor, which I don't want. Passing values to `MyObj` which are valid objects for the bytes constructor works, and `newmyobj` gets the value of that bytes object.
I believe I'm thinking too much C++...

---

If its still unclear what I want, here is a working C++ example doing the correct thing:

```
#include <vector>

struct list {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

class MyObj : std::vector<char> {
public:
    MyObj(list data) {
        this->resize(sizeof(data));
        std::copy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data)
                , reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data.x)+sizeof(data)
                , this->begin());
    }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    list data = {0.4,2.5,12.1};
    MyObj newmyobj = MyObj(data);
}
```

The MyObj could then be used everywhere, where a std::vector can be used, and have all the other convenience C++ containers have.

Comment: To me, it looks like your trying to do two different things in your examples

Comment: That may be true, but for me they look the same, which is probably also part of my problem. To break it down:
In both examples, I'm deriving a class from a base class that the language uses to store binary data. In both examples, I want to pass data to the constructor of the derived class, which is NOT valid data for the base class, to initialize the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__()` is not the constructor. You need to implement `__new__()`, which is really the constructor. For example:

```
class MyObj(bytes):
    def __new__(cls, data):
        # do operations here
        # dummy example
        new_data = [int(x) for x in data]
        return super().__new__(cls, new_data)

newmyobj = MyObj([0.4,2.5,12.1])
```

Also `bytes` are immutable. Therefore, doing something in `__init__()` might be too late.